# Localhost htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

I am using **.htaccess** file on my localhost and write this code:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^about/?$    about.php    [NC,L]
```

I have checked **http.doc** file everthing is fine. But its not working fine.

Thanks.

Comment: In what way is it not working fine? 500 error? 404 error? blank page?

Comment: not error when i click on about us page. Its show me localhost/abc/about.php but i want this localhost/abc/about

Comment: Is the `href` of the link `about.php` or `about`? That rewrite rule won't redirect from `about.php` to `about` - it just means that visiting `/about` will render `/about.php`

Comment: Is the .htaccess on the folder abc or the root folder?

Comment: yes htaccess in href="about.php" SmokeyPHP

Comment: Prix: htaccess file in abc folder

Comment: Then change the href to `href="/abc/about"`, if the link is `about.php` of course that's where you'll be taken! If this can't be changed for whatever reason you'd need a redirect rule (`RewriteRule ^about\.php about [R=301,L]`) above your current one.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP that would produce a infinite loop you need to either use the request for one or another in order to prevent that.

Comment: @Prix No it wouldn't, as long as you don't put `R=*` on the `^about` rule

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yep it does you can try it yourself if u want.

Comment: @Prix Sorry, yea - pure htaccess does go wrong. I remembered doing it before, but I've just remembered it incorporated a PHP router.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP like I mentioned early and on my answer using the request this can be archived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the .htaccess on the `www` folder and place the content on it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^abc/about\.html/?$ /abc/about.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Its not not working man... may be its localhost server problem i m using appserv.

Comment: @LeeAustin check if mod_rewrite is enable on the apache httpd.conf, if it is then it should work. **If you have just changed it you need to restart the server.**

Comment: Now its working fine when i move htaccess file on root www Thanks.

Comment: @LeeAustin try to copy the .htaccess from the www to the abc and then delete it from the www and let me know if it works.

Comment: its working but i need about.html its showing me abc/about/ in url